# How to write functions of functions in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am supposed to write a function called `(nth-filtered f n)`, where `f` is a function of one variable and n is a natural number, which evaluates to the nth natural number such that `f` applied to that number is `#t`.

If we called 
`(nth-filtered even? 1)` we would get 2

`(nth-filtered prime? 10)` we would get 29

How do I make it so that it works for any sequential function? What should I think about when approaching this type of problem?

Comment: You need either a helper function, since you have to keep track of both `n` and "the current number", or a lazy sequence that you can filter.

Comment: It's not very clear what the "sequential function" you're referring to is.

Comment: Sequential function is 1,2,3,4,5,... or 2,4,6,8,10... or 1,3,5,7,9...

Comment: I would call those "sequences", not "functions", but it's not clear how that is connected to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A variable is a variable and `+` is also a variable. The main difference between a function and some other data type is that you can wrap a function name in parentheses with arguments and it will become a new value.

eg.

```
(define (double fun) 
  (lambda (value) 
    (fun (fun value))))

(define (add1 v)
  (+ 1 v))

(define add2 (double add1))

(add2 1) ; ==> 3
```

Now the contract doesn't say so you deduct by looking that you do `(fun ...)` that `fun` needs to be a function. Imagine this:

```
(define test (double 5)) ; probably works OK
(test 1)
```

The last one fails since you get `application: 5 is not a procedure` or something similar. The error message is not standardized.

How to attack your task is by making a helper that has the same arguments as your function but in addition the current number that I guess starts at 1. As I demonstrated you use the function variable as a function and recurse by always increasing the number and reducing `n` when the `f` call was `#t`. The actual function will just use the helper by passing all the parameters in addition to your state variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem requires a fold, which is the standard way to iterate other a list while keeping a record of things done so far.

Here a very rackety method using [for/fold](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Fand#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffold%29%29):

```
(define (nth-filtered predicate index)
  (for/fold ([count 0]
             [current #f] #:result current)
            ([n (in-naturals 1)]) ; we start at 1 but we could start at 0
            #:break (= count index)
    (values (if (predicate n) (add1 count) count)
            n)))
```

`for/fold` takes a list of initial state. Here we define `count` as the number of times the given predicate returned `#t` and `current` as the currently tested value.

Then it takes a list of iterators, in this case we only iterate infinitely over `(in-naturals)`.

To make it stop, we provide a `#:break` condition, which is "when the number of truthy predicates (`count`) is equal to the requested amount (`index`)".

`for/fold` requests that it's body finishes with a list of values for each "state" variable, in order to update them for the next iteration. Here we provide two values: one is the new `count`, the other is just the current `n`.

You can try it out, it works as you requested:

```
> (nth-filtered even? 1)
2
> (require math/number-theory)
> (nth-filtered prime? 10)
29
> (nth-filtered prime? 5)
11
```